# Twitter4j vs Twitter hbc

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-hbc

I have used Twitter4j in past to read twitter public stream but have not used twitter hbc (which is twitter's official java library for streaming apis).

My use-case is to :

- Listen to a twitter stream based on certain filter query.

My question is ?

**what is your experience with these two above library and which is more suitable for usecase like mine**

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

If you want to see the tweets tweeted about your search criteria right now in real time: go for hbc-twitter4j.

If you have questions like: get me up to date what happened in the recent past about your search criteria: go for Twitter4J.

**Some details why**

**hbc** is good at network reconnecting and network error handling in the background. This gives you a stable real time stream, especially with a bad network.

This is good if you watch what happens right now for hours.

I did not find a way to select the recent days like with Twitter4J.

**Twitter4J**: unlike hbc, it is easy to ask Twitter4J what happened in the recent past.

Twitter4J has some maintenance, hbc does not.

**Both** can store the result in Twitter4J classes like Status to give you easy access to the relevant Twitter fields.